Sound problem Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Vivobook S14 M433UA
I am using Ubuntu for web development work. The system is fully functional on my laptop and everything seems to be fine, but there is one thing, my laptop has speakers from Harman/Kardon and on Windows they sound really amazing. However, on Ubuntu the sound seems to become mono rather than stereo, and significantly loses volume. To be more precise, it feels like there are no drivers for this specific device. I will be glad and grateful for any help.
My device: Vivobook S14 M433UA
